# Woocommerce: How to redirect to a new page from 'process_payment' function?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to build a custom payment gateway on Woocommerce.
And I'm trying to redirect to a new page for payment page from process_payment.

Is there any proper way to redirect to a page and also I can pass the data I need?

My folder struct:

```
wp-content
|_ plugins
   |_ my-payment
      |_ redirect_page.php
         wc_my_gateway.php
```

The process_payment function I have edit so far in wc_my_gateway.php :

```
public function process_payment($order_id)
{
        global $woocommerce;
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        
        // todo something ...
        
        $redirect_url = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'redirect_page.php';
        return [
            'result' => 'success', // return success status
            'redirect' => $redirect_url, // web page url to redirect
        ];
}
```

***If there any further information need, please feel free to comment.***

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Bhautik Thank for your comment. I even can't redirect to the page I wanted...
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()`

I think it cause by I didn't setup the redirect URL correctly. So I'm looking for a proper way to redirect to a page and also I can pass the data to the new page.

Comment: did you check the error logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
The following code is the solution for me.
Since I only need to redirect to somewhere for client to process payment, by redirecting to `/checkout/order-pay` page, I can try to custom what I need for the payment process with my own gateway.

```
public function process_payment($order_id){

  ...

  return [
     'result' => 'success', // return success status
     'redirect' => apply_filters('process_payment_redirect', $order->get_checkout_payment_url(true), $order), // web page redirect
  ];
}
```